# How to set objects name if I only have the number of enum

Tags: c#

How to set objects name if I only have the number of enum!

See in code what I meanm Im bad to explain

//Working
//Not Working

Code

```
public enum CarColor
{
    Red = 0,
    Blue= 1,     
}

public class CarColor
{
    public virtual CarColor Id { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{       
    public virtual int Customnumber{ get; set; }
    public virtual CarColor CarColorNumber{ get; set; }       
}


Public SaveIt(Car car)
{
  car.CarColorNumber= CarColor.Blue;  //Working
  car.CarColorNumber= 1;  // not Workingm the color for blue
}
```

Comment: That should already work, because there's an implicit conversion from 0 to any enum type... what do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Please put more effort into your sample code - you've currently got two types called `CarColor`, your method isn't part of a type, has a capital P and no return value. We should be able to copy and paste sample code straight into a text edit, then compile it.

Comment: It can't be a very good idea having an enum and a class with the same name

Comment: This question got ghost edited , earlier there was `car.CarColorNumber= 1;` and that was not working, but OP changed it to `0` and now there shouldn't be any error.

Comment: @Habib why shouldn't it be working with 1 ?

Comment: @Selman22, because for any value other than `0` it requires explicit casting.

Comment: The example was bad, now its a little bit better, sorry!

Comment: It must be like below if its bigger than 0
     car.CarColorNumber = (CarColor)1;

Comment: Sorry, Next time I will do a better example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The supposedly problematic line already works:

```
// This compiles fine
car.CarColorNumber = 0;
```

It wouldn't compile for any integer value *other* than a constant of 0, however. There's an implicit conversion from a constant value of 0 to any enum type, but for anything else it's an *explicit* conversion. So for example:

```
int number = 0;
// number is a variable, not a constant expression, so you need to cast.
car.CarColorNumber = (CarColor) number;
```